# Initializing user object onCreate android

Tags: android, mysql

So I'm struggling with this algorithm design. I'm writing an android app that has a user object. This object has a list of friends. It also can gain new friends using wifi direct and interacting with other users who also have the app. What's the best way to:
listen for requests
update the database.

The app will also have a web version, they both use the same MySQL database to store the data.

Comment: please do share your code for doubt.

Answer (score 0):

## This is for you, my Friend!

[UserGrid](https://developers.apigee.com/app-services) is an opensource library from Apigee which does this. The full monty, users groups, social graph, the likes, storing user data. Everything. Check it out!

PS: I'm in no way related to the Apigee company.